# How to get the two desired paths?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, I print a selected subdirectory from a parent directory. I made a function.

1. This function `listdirs()` is to call the specific subdirectory according to the given index.

But when I call this function two times, it gives me the same path two times.

**Given result**

```
Directory1: /home/bilal/Videos/folder1/fd
Directory2: /home/bilal/Videos/folder1/fd
```

**Expected result**

```
Directory1: /home/bilal/Videos/folder1/fd
Directory2: /home/bilal/Videos/folder2/fd
```

**Code**

```
import os    
  
subDir = []
def listdirs(path, which_dir):
    for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for dir in dirs:
            d = os.path.join(roots, dir)
            subDir.append(d)
    b = [s.split() for s in subDir]
    letme = b[which_dir]
    run = [str(i) for i in letme]  
    result = "".join(run)           # Removing the []
    return result

rootdir1 = '/home/bilal/Videos/folder1'
directory1 = listdirs(rootdir1, 2)
print(f"Directory1: {directory1}")

rootdir2 = '/home/bilal/Videos/folder2'
directory2 = listdirs(rootdir2, 2)
print(f"Directory2: {directory2}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You should define `subDir = []` inside the function `listdirs`, before the for loop.

**Long Answer**

`subDir` is a `list`, which, in Python, is a mutable object. That means the object that the variable `subDir` is pointing to can change. Every time you append to `subDir` in `listdirs`, you are appending to the *original* object. So every time you try to get the second directory from `subDirs`, you are getting the same second directory that was added to it the first time you ran `listdirs`.

It's a good idea to avoid global mutable variables unless you know exactly what's going to happen with them.

Also, I think your function could be simplified a bit:

```
def listdirs(path, which_dir):
    subdirs = []
    for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for dir in dirs:
            d = os.path.join(roots, dir)
            subdirs.append(d)
    result = subdirs[which_dir]
    return result
```